# JsonMappingException can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to insert object in my database but i am getting this error

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer out of VALUE_TRUE token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@745b0b15; line: 1, column: 353] (through reference chain: com.example.beans.Domain["isActive"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer out of VALUE_TRUE token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@745b0b15; line: 1, column: 353] (through reference chain: com.example.beans.Domain["isActive"])
```

my code is:

```
@Entity
public class Domain implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    ...
    private Integer isActive;

    public Integer getIs_active() {
        return isActive;
    }
    public void setIs_active(Integer is_active) {
        this.isActive = is_active;
    }
```

Comment: Integar is scalar, try to get the "String" value for json. Check this thread https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/139

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your JSON for isActive is of boolean `isActive : true`
It is expecting to be of type boolean not integer.
This is makes your Jackson

Change your  `private Integer isActive;` to `private boolean isActive;`

Answer (score 0):

Your getter and setter methods for isActive should be getIsActive and setIsActive without underscore

```
public Integer getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
}

public void setIsActive(Integer is_active) {
        this.isActive = is_active;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test the API throw postman you , And if you have only on input of type integer you should send it direct to body without json object braces.

Check below images for more details

[image: Sample API , POST , Take only one parameter]

[image: Example how to pass parameter from postman]